# Changing Hadoop Username during runtime doesn't work

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I wrote a little Hadoop Client Java application, that lists all files in HDFS (unsecure) and all tables in Hive, and some more stuff. However, I need to change the Hadoop Username during runtime.

Setting the name via `System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "testuser");` works fine for the first time I need this username. But when I want to change the username to e.g. `System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs");` I get an exception (after setting the hadoop username to hdfs as shown above):

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=testuser, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/app-logs/ambari-qa":ambari-qa:hadoop:drwxrwx---
```

What could be the problem here? Why can't I just change the username via the HADOOP_USER_NAME property whenever I want to?

**EDIT**

Can I just use `UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser(username));` to change the user during runtime or are there some restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are connecting to HDFS or Hive using JDBC connection.
Till you close the existing connection , you cannot make one more connection from the same application to HDFS/Hive service .